# Laravel - Can't access pivot table data

Tags: sqlite, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, pivot-table

I'm having a hard time getting Eloquent to play nice; it seems there's always something wrong with my queries. Anyways, I have a class `Item` with a many-to-many relationship to `Length` through the `r_item_length` table. In the pivot table, there is also a `value` field. Here is the `Item` model:

**models/db/Item.php:**

```
class Item extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    ...

    protected $fillable = ['item_singular', 'item_plural'];

    public function length() 
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('Length', 'r_item_length')->withPivot('value');
        }
}
```

I am trying to get the `value` from the pivot table for a given `Item`. Currently, I'm trying to access it in my view like so:

**views/db/show.blade.php**

```
<body>
    <table>
    @foreach ($items as $item)
        <tr class="record">
            <td>{{ $item->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->item_singular }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->item_plural }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>{{ var_dump($item->length->first()->pivot->value) }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </table>
</body>
```

`$item->length->first()->pivot` is what's giving me the the error: "**Trying to get property of non-object**". After searching for several hours, it appears this syntax SHOULD be acceptable, `$item->length->first()->pivot->value`, but I can't get it to work. I've also tried it this way, `$item->length->pivot->value`, but of course, it doesn't work since I've defined a many-to-many relationship between the two.

Is this an indication of something wrong with the way my models are set up? Am I just querying it incorrectly? Thanks for your help.

Below is the output of the first item from `var_dump($item->length->first())`.

```
object(Length)[167]
  protected 'table' => string 'length' (length=6)
  protected 'hidden' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'fillable' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'length_short' (length=12)
      1 => string 'length_long_singular' (length=20)
      2 => string 'length_long_plural' (length=18)
  protected 'connection' => null
  protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
  protected 'perPage' => int 15
  public 'incrementing' => boolean true
  public 'timestamps' => boolean true
  protected 'attributes' => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'length_short' => string 'ft' (length=2)
      'length_long_singular' => string 'Foot' (length=4)
      'length_long_plural' => string 'Feet' (length=4)
      'created_at' => string '2015-01-10 11:00:49' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2015-01-10 11:00:49' (length=19)
  protected 'original' => 
    array (size=9)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'length_short' => string 'ft' (length=2)
      'length_long_singular' => string 'Foot' (length=4)
      'length_long_plural' => string 'Feet' (length=4)
      'created_at' => string '2015-01-10 11:00:49' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2015-01-10 11:00:49' (length=19)
      'pivot_item_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'pivot_length_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'pivot_value' => string '1.2' (length=3)
  protected 'relations' => 
    array (size=1)
      'pivot' => 
        object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot)[172]
          protected 'parent' => 
            object(Item)[165]
              ...
          protected 'foreignKey' => string 'item_id' (length=7)
          protected 'otherKey' => string 'length_id' (length=9)
          protected 'guarded' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'connection' => null
          protected 'table' => string 'r_item_length' (length=13)
          protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
          protected 'perPage' => int 15
          public 'incrementing' => boolean true
          public 'timestamps' => boolean false
          protected 'attributes' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          protected 'original' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          protected 'relations' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'hidden' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'visible' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'appends' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'fillable' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'dates' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'touches' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'observables' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'with' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'morphClass' => null
          public 'exists' => boolean true
  protected 'visible' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'appends' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'guarded' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '*' (length=1)
  protected 'dates' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'touches' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'observables' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'with' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'morphClass' => null
  public 'exists' => boolean true
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have items that have no `Length` assigned? so `$item->length->first()` would return `null`?

Comment: :facepalm: That was exactly the issue! I don't know why that didn't occur to me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem happens to be that some `Item`s don't have a `Length` assigned. So `$item->length->first()` is null and therefore accessing `pivot` raises the error. The solution for this is fairly simple. Just wrap an if around it and you should be fine.

```
<tr>
    @if($length = $item->length->first())
        <td>{{ $length->pivot->value }}</td>
    @endif
</tr>
```

Comment: Yep, I'll definitely being doing that, once I flesh out my app some more. Thanks!